# Tengo dos preguntas. espero me puedan ayudar

Tags: java

¿Los arraylist son arreglos?

¿Así se hacen las colas en java?

Queue cola = new LinkedList();

gracias.

Answer (score 1):

`Queue` es una interfaz para colas, eso significa que puedes crear colas usando diferentes implementaciones como por ejemplo `LinkedList`, por lo tanto, sí, es correcto crear una cola de esa manera. Otras implementaciones para crear colas podrían ser `LinkedBlockingQueue` , `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` o `ArrayBlockingQueue`.

Lo mismo pasa con el `List`, es una interfaz para listas y puedes usar diferentes implementaciones para crearlas. Una de ellas es `ArrayList`.

**Lo importante es saber cual usar y cuando, y eso depende de lo que necesites hacer. Algunas funcionan mejor que otras en diferentes escenarios.**

Answer (score 0):

A la primera pregunta, correcto, son arreglos o arrays.

La segunda, bien tambien, aunque es cierto que existen mas interfaces para crear arrays en Java. Aqui te dejo un enlace a los distintos metodos para poder crear abstracciones de estructuras de datos:

[Estucturas de datos en Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/package-tree.html)

Saludos.

Comment: `ArrayList` no es un arreglo es una lista aunque la estructura subyacente sea un arreglo.

Comment: Cierto...tienes razón, vaya fallo, bastante distinto es una Lista en estructura de datos a un array,  aunque como tu dices para construir esa estructura de datos sea usado por Java un array para conseguirlo. ¿Como se tacha para corregir la respuesta?

Comment: Usa la opción editar

Answer (score 0):

Los arreglos también son llamados Arrays, y también matrices. Estos 3 términos hacen referencia al mismo tipo de objeto. Son 3 formas de llamar a la misma cosa, igual que atún y bonito hacen referencia al mismo pez.

Sin embargo, los ArrayList no son Arrays, son listas. Igual que un cuadro bonito no es un bonito. Por lo tanto, se deduce que un arreglo (o array) **NO** es un arrayList.

Como dicen los contertulios, cada uno es más efectivo que el otro en cada situación. Y un buen programador conocerá los 2 y sabrá cuando va mejor 1 y cuando mejor el otro. En el curso, tutorial, libro, lo que sea que utilice cada 1 como fuente de aprendizaje, debería de explicar cada 1 y en base a sus características, el programador debe decidir cuando es mejor 1 y cuando el otro.